# Как передать параметр в контроллер?

Tags: php

В общем вопрос состоит в том как осуществить передачу параметра в контроллер используя маршрутизацию? например строка вида: http://example.ru/control/action/parametr
использую следующую маршрутизацию:

```
static function start()
{
    // контроллер и действие по умолчанию
    $controller_name = 'Main';
    $action_name = 'index';

    $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // получаем имя контроллера
    if ( !empty($routes[1]) )
    {
        $controller_name = $routes[1];
    }

    // получаем имя экшена
    if ( !empty($routes[2]) )
    {
        $action_name = $routes[2];
    }


    // добавляем префиксы
    $model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
    $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

    // подцепляем файл с классом модели 

    $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
    if(file_exists($model_path))
    {
        include "application/models/".$model_file;
    }

    // подцепляем файл с классом контроллера
    $controller_file = strtolower($controller_name).'.php';
    $controller_path = "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    if(file_exists($controller_path))
    {
        include "application/controllers/".$controller_file;
    }
    else
    {

        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

    // создаем контроллер
    $controller = new $controller_name;
    $action = $action_name;

    if(method_exists($controller, $action))
    {
        // вызываем действие контроллера
        $controller->$action();
    }
    else
    {

        Route::ErrorPage404();
    }

}
```

Comment: вы два уровня использовали, а остальные можно отдать как аргументы  к методу, например так `call_user_func_array([$controller, $action], array_slice($routes, 2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$controller_name = 'Main';
$action_name = 'index';
$params = [];

$routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// получаем имя контроллера
if ( isset($routes[1]) ) {
  $controller_name = $routes[1];
}

// получаем имя экшена
if ( isset($routes[2]) ) {
  $action_name = $routes[2];
}

// получаем параметры
if ( isset($routes[3]) ) {
  $params = array_slice($routes, 3);
}

echo $controller_name."<br />";
echo $action_name."<br />";
print_r($params);
```

Тогда передав GET-параметры скрипту /controller/action/2016/04/24, вы сможете получить их в массиве `$params`

```
controller
action
Array ( [0] => 2016 [1] => 04 [2] => 24 )
```

Comment: круто, только в вопросе совсем другая структура url

Comment: @splash58, да действительно, придется переработать

Comment: мой коммент моежте использовать :)

Comment: Поправил. Да, array_slice() тоже сразу в голову пришел :)

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер!
Точно так же, как Вы получаете имя контроллера и экшена из массива $routes, Вам необходимо получить значение параметров. Для Вашего примера:

```
// получаем значение переданного параметра
if ( !empty($routes[3]) )
{
    $params= $routes[3];
}
```

Аналогично можно получить остальные параметры, если их больше одного, а затем передать их в метод контроллера, используя функцию call_user_func_array() . 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php

Также рекомендую посмотреть в сторону различных микрофреймворков, таких как Slim, Silex, etc.